# exec() not working on Debian 7

Tags: java, linux, debian, exec, keytool

I created an SSL certificate via `keytool` automatically within my program by using `Runtime.getRuntime().exec()` and it is working fine on Windows.

When I try to run my code on Debian 7 it just doesn't execute the command. Well, it does execute but it returns error code 1 which basically means something went wrong.

If I let my program print the string to execute and then execute this command manually, then everything works fine.

Here's the code with some debugging outputs:

```
private static void initKeystore()
{
    Scanner scr = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("**** IMPORTANT ****");
    System.out.println("You don't have a certificate for using SSL yet.");
    System.out.println("We will create it together now!");
    System.out.println();
    System.out.print("Name of your organisation: ");
    String ssl_o = scr.nextLine();
    String ssl_ou = ssl_o;
    System.out.print("Your name: ");
    String ssl_cn = scr.nextLine();
    System.out.print("Country code [de/en/fr]: ");
    String ssl_c = scr.nextLine();
    System.out.print("City: ");
    String ssl_l = scr.nextLine();
    System.out.print("State: ");
    String ssl_st = scr.nextLine();
    System.out.print("Password: ");
    String pass = new String(scr.nextLine());

    String execString = "keytool -genkey -keyalg RSA -alias dreamim -keystore " + KEYSTORE + " -storepass " + pass + " -validity 360 -dname \"cn=" + ssl_cn + ", o=" + ssl_o + ", ou=" + ssl_ou + ", c=" + ssl_c + ", l=" + ssl_l + ", st=" + ssl_st + "\" -keypass " + pass;
    System.out.println(execString);
    try
    {
        Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(execString);

        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(proc.getInputStream()));
        String line;
        while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null)
        {
            System.out.println(line);
        }
        bufferedReader.close();

        proc.waitFor();
        System.out.println("Key generation exited with code: " + proc.exitValue());

        execString = "keytool -export -keystore " + KEYSTORE + " -storepass " + pass + " -alias dreamim -file DreamIM.crt";
        proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(execString);
        proc.waitFor();

    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
            // TODO: Improve exception handling
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    scr.close();
}
```

My code is not throwing any exceptions...
Is there any known compatibility problem with `exec()` and Debian 7 (OpenJDK)?

Comment: "*Is there any known compatibility problem with exec() and Debian 7 (OpenJDK)?*" => no. Show your code.

Comment: `keytool` can be particular about the order of arguments. You need to show some code.

Comment: I edited the question and added some code. I am pretty sure that it's not the order of arguments because as I said in my question, when I execute the keytool command manually, everything works fine and in Windows it also runs automatically with this code. It's only Linux where it is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally managed to fix the problem. It was as simple as I thought. I just used the exec(String[]) method and supplied the arguments by hand.
I guess it was something like the -dname option was not escaped properly and Windows ignored that or corrected it automatically.